# How to extract Jenkinsfile by a custom script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a Jenkins job of type "Pipeline", and used an inline pipeline script. Now I'd like to put the script under version control and use the "Pipeline script from SCM" option (I think, I don't have to describe the merits of this).

However, our version control system (CA SCM) is not well supported in Jenkins: I couldn't make the plugin to check out anything.

We do have, however, some scripts for working with CA SCM that allow to check out things reliably.

So, my question is: Is it possible (and how) to have the Jenkinsfile under version control, do the check out for it by a custom script (e.g. using a .bat command) and then have the pipeline executed as if the Jenkinsfile had been extracted by the "Pipeline script from SCM" option?

I.e., as I understand it, I need a command in the pipeline plugin to execute a given Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the feature "Prepare an environment for the build" from the "Environment Injector Plugin" (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and provide a script file (or inlined content) to execute.